# How do I extract the structure from a list of strings?

Tags: linux, text-processing, data-processing

Say I have a list of similarly structured strings stored in a file:

```
Jenny lives in New York. She is 22 and a machinist.
Tommy lives in Los Angeles. He is 21 and a ballet dancer.
Kevin lives in Boston. He is 7 and jobless.
```

Now I'd like to extract the identical structure as well as parts that are
different in these strings. Ideally, I should obtain:

```
structure == "%s lives in %s. %se is %d and %s."
data == [ 
  [ "Jenny" , "New York"    , "Sh" , 22 , "a machinist"     ] ,
  [ "Tommy" , "Los Angeles" , "H"  , 21 , "a ballet dancer" ] ,
  [ "Kevin" , "Boston"      , "H"  , 7  , "jobless"         ]
]
```

Not that the `structure` is unknown and should be calculated from the list of strings. Precisely, a **structure** is defined as the longest common sub-sequence possible across all strings.

What is the easiest way to achieve this using any tool or language commonly seen in a linux environment?

---

**Edit:** to clarify, these strings can be arbitrary and don't have to be in natural language. However the above example is pretty much what I expect to do in 99% of the time. I currently define "structure" as the longest common sub-sequence possible across all strings (unless the method could be much easier or faster if I make the definition a little bit lenient).

**Edit2:** I see a misunderstanding of the question in the answers. Here the `structure` is **not predefined** and should be **calculated from** the list of strings.

Comment: Are you trying to extract information from  Structured String ? If that's the case than any programming Language Will Suffice. If you are looking to extract Information from Natural Language then you'll need to use a Natural Language Processor like [link](https://opennlp.apache.org/) Or the ALchemyApi from IBM watson for example

Comment: @ketrox Thanks for the answer but my problem really doesn't have to be in natural language. It could be any strings. I am aware that the language doesn't matter, I mentioned that because I don't care which language the answer is written in as long as I can understand how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

I Wrote a little Java Programm That does what i think you need:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    static String string1="Jenny lives in NewYork . She is 22 and a machinist.";
    static String string2="Tommy lives in LosAngeles . He is 21 and a ballet dancer.";
    static String string3="Kevin lives in Boston . He is 7 and a jobless.";
    static String string4="Ketrox lives in UnderAbridge . He is 8 and a jobless.";
    public static String findReferenceString(List<String> data){
        Set<String> res =new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(data.get(0).split(" ")));
        for(int i=1; i<data.size();i++){
            Set<String> nx=new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(data.get(i).split(" ")));
            res.retainAll(nx);
            System.out.println(res);//debug
            }
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for(String s: res)
            sb.append(s+' ');
        return sb.toString();

        }
    public static String extractFromString(String structure,String relevantData){
        Set<String> nx=new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(structure.split(" ")));
        Set<String> ny=new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(relevantData.split(" ")));
         ny.removeAll(nx);
         return ny.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(string1);
        list.add(string2);
        list.add(string3);
        list.add(string4);
        System.out.println(extractFromString(findReferenceString(list),string1));




    }

}
```

The output would be:

```
[a, lives, in, and, is, .]
[a, lives, in, and, is, .]
[a, lives, in, and, is, .]
[22, She, NewYork, Jenny, machinist.]
```

Hope This Helps you further. Note That you can tweak this code to go into details(chars instead of Strings)